# Any ideas on how to format these lines in vim?

Tags: vim

I have the following lines that I've already formatted quite a bit, but I can't seem to figure out how to format these jagged lines so they are all in the correct position. I've been trying using macros and also using `/s` but it just seems the tabs or spaces after the word is a bit different for each. What might be a good way to format this here?

[image]

Comment: You would probably need a plugin such as vim align plugin. Otherwise you can use a sophisticated regex search and replace to format these lines to conform to some template of your choosing.

Comment: Please replace that image with the text it contains

Comment: @AD7six I'm sorry I've since fixed it and don't have the previous text as it was.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the entire part you want to format and then use the normal command

```
'<,'>s/\([^: ]\+\)[ ]*:[ ]*\([^: ]*\)/\=printf('%-8s%8s%s%8s%8s',submatch(1),' ',':',' ',submatch(2))/g
```

which will pad the result evenly around the `:`.

You can select in `vim` using `v` then enter normal mode with `esc` followed by entering command mode with `:`. Paste the above line in command mode once the selection is made and hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

Use [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align). And Select the text you need to align. Input `ga*:`. Done.